# How to set custom attributes for laravel validation instead of numeric keys?

Tags: php, validation, laravel, laravel-4

**How to send the values for laravel validation ?**

```
$data = explode(",", trim(Input::get('Vehicle_Data')));  //exploding data
$rule  =  array(
$data[0] => 'required',
$data[1] => 'required',
$data[2] => 'required|email|unique:users'
              ) ;
$validator = Validator::make($data,$rule);
if ($validator->fails())
   {
    $messages = $validator->messages();
    return $messages;
    }
else
    {
    return 'ok'
    }
```

I just want to check the whether the $data[0] is required and should be unique

**It works good when it is**

```
'email' => 'required|email|unique:users'
```

**But not working when it is**

```
$data[2] => 'required|email|unique:users'
```

But i don't want to declare $data[2] into another variable and do it how can i do this without assigning data[2] to another variable

**When ever i validate it is returning**

```
Object {32: Array[1], 43: Array[1]}
```

in the console

Comment: $data[2} << typo here or your error in the file?

Comment: No no, that's just typo while typing it. It was $data[1] in the file

Comment: What is the value from `Input::get('Vehicle_Data')`

Comment: @Jerodev : **["l", "l", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "Contract", "9", "10"] This is the value from Input::get('Vehicle_Data')**

Comment: That will never work, the keys of the array need to be the names of the fields, not the values.

Comment: It is not even possible atleast to check the first key , second key like that ?

Comment: @Jerodev It will work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's probably not the best idea to do it the way you're trying, but here is how you achieve what you want:

```
$data = explode(",", trim(Input::get('Vehicle_Data')));  //exploding data

$rules = array(
   'required',
   'required',
   'required|email|unique:users,email'
);
```

`$data` will be simple array with numeric keys, so the `$rules` array should be just the same and it will work.

---

edit: as per comment, `Validator::make` is capable of **1** set custom messages, **2** set custom attributes. So for you the latter is the way to go:

```
$messages = []; // no need to specify that, unless you'd like
$attributes = ['id', 'name', 'email', ...]; // use your actual fields here

$validator = Validator::make($data, $rules, $messages, $attributes);

// then the messages will use $attributes array, so will show:
'The name has already been taken'
'The email field is required'

// instead of:
'The 1 has already been taken'
'The 2 field is required'
```

Comment: But while checking for `'required|email|unique:users'` It shows **SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column '3' in 'where clause' (SQL: select count(*) as aggregate from `vehicle` where `3` = 432)"** as the we have 3 as the $rule name

Comment: Just add another param to that rule specifying the column - like in my edit.

Comment: Thanks, so that the validator will return **The 2 has already been taken.**  and **The 0 field is required."** like this right ??

Comment: That's right. But remember that you can pass custom messages as 3rd parameter of `make` method, so it can be whatever you like.

Comment: I don't understand it, But Custom Error Messages is the thing i wanted to do while validator fails , Can you please update how to do it

Comment: I mean to say It's returning **{"2":["The 2 has already been taken."]}** But I don't know how to make it as **{"2":["The Email has already been taken."]}** like this

Comment: For this you need custom attributes, not custom messages. Check the edit, there's all you need.

Comment: That's is really awesome, Thanks